# Color a cell if the difference between sequential cells in a column meets a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm keeping a gas mileage spreadsheet. Column A contains the odometer reading each time I fill the tank. I would like to compare the difference between a cell and the preceding cell.  If the difference is > 499 color the cell with the larger number green.

Ex:

```
       A
    1 519
    2 1002
    3 1496
    4 2014
    5 2445
    6 2796
```

Subtract A1 from A2 if the difference is greater than 499 color A2 green.  I'm looking for a formula that will do this for the entire column.  In this example A4 should be green.

Comment: Are you familiar with conditional formatting? You can write your own formula to set the color of a cell. Probably something like color the cell green with the formula =(A2-A1)>499.  Then apply it to that column.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I had tried several variations but didn't have the syntax correct.  I failed to mention in my question that I'm using google docs not MS Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what was suggested in the comment above (Conditional Formatting) in a picture. (Note: this is Excel 2013 -- it may look different in your version):

In this case I selected the cells to format as A2 to the last row in the worksheet to make sure all of the column was formatted as new data is added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way you could try is to create a custom formula, save it, then create a macro to run on that entire column when the spreadsheet is open.

This should help get you started:    http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/running-a-macro-when-excel-starts-HA001034628.aspx